# Maximum number divisible by another one created from sum of previous numbers

Tags: algorithm, concatenation, dynamic-programming

There are given numbers `1, 2, ...., b-1`. Every number of these can be used `a[1], a[2], ...., a[b-1]` times.

From them the biggest possible number (from data given) has to be concatenated, while sum of its digits (partial numbers) has to be divisible by `b`. "Digits" of this number can be of any base bigger than 2.
So basically the biggest number of base `b` has to be created, by concatenating numbers `1...b-1`, up to `a[1]...a[b-1]` times each, while sum of all used partial numbers/digits has to be divisible by `b`.

For example:
There is 5 times `1`, 10 times `2`, 4 times `3` and 2 times `4`. As stated above, they have to concatenate the biggest number divisible by `b` (here `5`).
They would give:
`44333322222222221111`.
Concatenating from the biggest to the lowest gives needed number, as their sum is divisible by 5.
For 1 times `1` it is:
`0`
Because 1 is not divisible by 2, so no numbers should be used then.

What are the algorithms or similar problems to this? How can it be approached?

At first, we can simply arrange numbers from the biggest to the lowest, so the concatenated number will naturally be the biggest. Then, we have to take the least amount of these numbers, so their sum will be divisible by `b`. When there can be taken different combinations of these numbers but in the same amounts, the one that has its biggest number the smallest among others should be choosen (or the second biggest and so on).
For example:
If combinations of `(3, 3, 2)` and `(4, 2, 2)` can be taken, then the first one should be cut out from the number.

This really looks like change-making problem, but with finite amount of coins of different denominations and at the end, we have to have the combination, not only the minimal amount of coins. In addition, with dynamic approach, 2 different combinations of same length (like `332` and `442` above) can't be rather easily chosen in the middle of dynamic array, as in next steps they can give quite much different values.